# upgrading jsserv giving this error: Could not install packages due to an OSError

Tags: jaseci

This is what I am getting when upgrading jaseci to the lastest version. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be running a jsserv server while trying to upgrade. You would have to kill that process first. Also try doing a `pip uninstall jaseci_serv` first.

Comment: Alright I will try that and see it that works